# How do I replace the nth occurrence of a special character, say, a pipe delimiter with another in Scala?

Tags: regex, scala, replaceall

I'm new to Spark using Scala and I need to replace every nth occurrence of the delimiter with the newline character.

So far, I have been successful at entering a new line **after** the pipe delimiter.
I'm unable to **replace** the delimiter itself.

My input string is

```
val txt = "January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December"

println(txt.replaceAll(".\\|", "$0\n"))
```

The above statement generates the following output.

```
January|
February|
March|
April|
May|
June|
July|
August|
September|
October|
November|
December
```

I referred to the suggestion at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189923/adding-comma-separator-for-every-nth-character but when I enter the number in the curly braces, I only end up adding the newline **after** 2 characters after the delimiter.

I'm expecting my output to be as given below.

```
January|February
March|April
May|June
July|August
September|October
November|December
```

How do I change my regular expression to get the desired output?

***Update:***
My friend suggested I try the following statement

```
println(txt.replaceAll("(.*?\\|){2}", "$0\n"))
```

and this produced the following output

```
January|February|
March|April|
May|June|
July|August|
September|October|
November|December
```

Now I just need to get rid of the pipe symbol at the end of each line.

Comment: you just want to print it on different lines or do something on the output that you receive. Even though you are doing println it would remain a single string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to move the 2nd bar `|` outside of the capture group.

```
txt.replaceAll("([^|]+\\|[^|]+)\\|", "$1\n")
//val res0: String =
//  January|February
//  March|April
//  May|June
//  July|August
//  September|October
//  November|December
```

---

**Regex Explained** (regex is not Scala)

- `(` - start a capture group
- `[^|]` - any character as long as it's not the bar `|` character
- `[^|]+` - 1 or more of those (any) non-bar chars
- `\\|` - followed by a single bar char `|`
- `[^|]+` - followed by 1 or more of any non-bar chars
- `)` - close the capture group
- `\\|` - followed by a single bar char (not in capture group)
- `"$1\n"` - replace the entire matching string with just the first `$1` capture group (`$0` is the entire matching string) followed by the newline char

---

**UPDATE**

For the general case of N repetitions, regex becomes a bit more cumbersome, at least if you're trying to do it with a single regex formula.

The simplest thing to do (not the most efficient but simple to code) is to traverse the `String` twice.

```
val n = 5
txt.replaceAll(s"(\\w+\\|){$n}", "$0\n")
   .replaceAll("\\|\n", "\n")
//val res0: String =
//  January|February|March|April|May
//  June|July|August|September|October
//  November|December
```

Comment: Thank you, @jwvh, this actually solved the problem in a single line.
But could you please explain the regex? Why are we using $1 instead of $0? And what does the pattern do?

P.S.: I'm new to Scala.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. If I were to change the value of (n), that is, if I were to replace the 4th or 5th occurrence of the | pipe symbol, then would I need to add as many [^|]+ in the capture group?

As to accepting of the answer and upvoting, I'd done both as soon as reading the answers and trying them out, but I guess neither of them has reflected. I've re-accepted and re-voted your answer.

P.S.: I'm new to StackOverflow as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You could first split the string using '|' to get the array of string and then loop through it to perform the logic you want and get the output as required.

```
val txt = "January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December"
val out = txt.split("\\|")
var output: String = ""
for(i<-0 until out.length -1 by 2){
  val ref = out(i) + "|" + out(i+1) + "\n"
  output = output + ref
}
val finalout = output.replaceAll("\"\"","")  //just to remove the starting double quote
println(finalout)
```